# Grabbing partial HTML

Tags: c#, html

I know of the use of 'WebClient' and 'client.DownloadString' to grab the pure HTML of a given URL without actually displaying the page. Is it possible to grab just one line or section of the HTML, without saving the entire HTML in the destination string? If I'm only seeking one small section of the HTML, it seems a little inefficient to take the entire page of it in one string, only to parse it into little segments thereafter.

Comment: I think RegEx is your answer for that.

Comment: @believeme Can you give me an example? I'm not particularly good with RegEx

Comment: To use RegEx you also have to download the whole html into a string. There is no way around this. You can't tell the webclient to download only a special part of a document. If you need help with RegEx, post a sample HTML file and tell us, which part you want to extract.

Comment: @netblognet Ok, fair enough. Would it be prudent to then use a stringbuilder for each line of HTML?

Comment: Why not just download the whole html into a string with DownloadString-method and then just run a RegEx over it, which extracts the relevant parts to a new string? After that you can throw away the initial string with the complete html.

Comment: @netblognet That's the general aim, I'm just concerned about the weight of the string primarily, as well as the fact that the URL I'm extracting is not guaranteed to be the same length every time. Scanning the text of the HTML for the end of the URL may prove to be kind of costly.

Comment: "is not guaranteed to be the same length every time" - that's where RegEx comes into play. So if you need concrete help building the RegEx, give 1-2 examples of the url's you want to extract. Or do you want to extract any url in the given html?

Comment: @netblognet No, I'm looking for a specific URL. I'm going to go off and try and learn something about RegEx, it's high time I did so. I'll pop back if I have any issues, thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Also notably, while expensive, HtmlAgilityPack can be very good for extracting information out of a webpage.